# Cakephp, an elegant solution to quantities?

Tags: php, cakephp, model, shopping-cart, behavior

I have a shopping cart system in Cakephp, this table has all your usual maguffins: user_ids, product_ids, option_lists ect. It also has quantity.

I currently have some awful nested loops to check if the record is the same as any in there, if so add one to the quantity. If not add a new cart item.

This loop has to check associated list items and product options, so it goes quite deep.

What I'm wondering is if there is a more elegant way of checking to see if two cart items in a database are similar (everything except for quantity).

Cheers!

Comment: Have you tried the approach from the book "Practical CakePHP Projects"? http://books.google.com/books?id=3S0O6Egf-_4C&pg=PA63&dq=%22the+cart+model%22&ei=6p39S6TFMaXKzASG4ZC9Dw&hl=ru&cd=1#v=onepage&q=%22the%20cart%20model%22&f=false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like something that the [`Set`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/640/Set) utility might be able to help with. I've never used it for this purpose, but perhaps `Set::isEqual()` or `Set::diff()` would get you where you want to be.

Comment: Yup, just remember to `unset` any keys you are not interested in before comparing.